# Program for known formats structure highlighting in binary format representation

Tags: macos, data-structures, format, visualization, data-visualization

Does somebody know a program for reading binary files and representing them with structure highlightning (coloring) for OS X:

something like this:

[image: but with data]

just to have faster and better overview of how the structure of the file looks like and what are the data of the interesting parts of the file, instead of counting byte offsets and writing bytes down...

Comment: would be great if the program could analyze the file and recognize, what kind of structure (file format) is it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe 010 Editor (at http://www.sweetscape.com) does what you want, not as a graph but as a tree of structures. At least, it is definitely superior to raw hex editing (though 010 Editor has that feature as well).

Comment: I saw the program before, but it seemed to me not so great, so I didn't try it. But now I tried it's trial version - it is not bad! Thank you!